# Perl Script in Bash Here Document (does not output variable)?

Tags: bash, shell, perl, here-document

How come the following perl code,

```
mkdir("foo");
print "foo: $!\n";
mkdir("foo");
print "foo: $!\n";
```

Will output the following **(in a directory without a `foo`)**

```
perl ./asdf.pl 
foo: 
foo: File exists
```

But removing `foo`, the following

```
$ perl <<EOF 
  mkdir("foo");
  print "foo: $!\n";
  mkdir("foo");
  print "foo: $!\n";
EOF
```

Swallows the error and outputs,

```
foo: 
foo:
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to quote the word `EOF`. From the docs (`man bash`),

> If any part of `word` is quoted, the delimiter is the result of quote  removal on `word`, and the lines in the here-document are not expanded.

So it'll look like,

```
$ perl <<'EOF'

EOF
```

If `EOF` is unquoted, the `$!` is interpolated from the shell before being sent to Perl.

```
$ cat <<EOF 
  mkdir("foo");
  print "foo: $!\n";
  mkdir("foo");
  print "foo: $!\n";
EOF
  mkdir("foo");
  print "foo: \n";
  mkdir("foo");
  print "foo: \n";
```